# Can I apply to student discount just with a school ID

Tags: apple-store

I'm an international student currently in an exchange program in a US school. I do have a student ID card, but that's it.

According to your experience, will I be able to get the student discount? Does it take some kind of digital validation?

As I said before, I have a student ID card from my school, but I don't have a valid .edu address or anything. Does Apple perform some kind of checkup or just showing the ID is enough?

Comment: I would like to add to this that if I borrow the card from a local student will it be crosschecked if person and the ID card match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your just looking for the ~5% student discount, yes your student ID card will be enough.

For the Apple On Campus 12% discout, they will check from your student card if your school is registered to this program.